# How to retrieve the last saved image from DCIM/Camera folder in sd card in Android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the last saved image from DCIM/Camera folder which is captured by camera and show it in an imageview in a particular activity.Can any please tell me how to retrieve the last saved image from DCIM/Camera folder by using the File class.Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you trying to capture image in your application?

Comment: yeah Sandeep..can you help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to use the MediaStore content provider to get images, order by date, max 1 result

Comment: Thanks Budius,but can you please provide me the source code to achieve this task??

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media.query(cr, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, orderBy)`

Answer (score 0):

To capture image from camera in your app you need to use intents, here is the example on how to capture image using android camera app.

[Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)